# Sending Ajax Request each time when user types username to check username availability. What drawbacks are there to this approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, mongoose

I am making a NodeJS authentication app.

Situation: The user types in a username, if the username is taken it will show "username taken" else it will show "username available"

I want to know the drawbacks of the method that I have implemented below:

**Username Input field**

```
<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username" required="" onkeyup="checkUsername(this.value)">
```

So on each time when the user types a letter, checkUsername() function is called!

**checkUsername function**

```
        function checkUsername(data){
            $( document ).ready(function(){

                
            $.ajax({
                url: '/register/checkUsername',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({user_name:data}),
                success: function(new_data) {
                    if(new_data == 'available'){
                        //By Default the messages are hidden!
                        document.getElementsByClassName('user-name-taken')[0].style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementsByClassName('user-name-available')[0].style.display = 'block'
                    } else  {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('user-name-available')[0].style.display = 'none'
                        document.getElementsByClassName('user-name-taken')[0].style.display = 'block'
                    }
                }
            })

            })
            
        }
```

**'/register/checkUsername' Router**

```
async (req,res)=>{
        var username = await userModel.findOne({userName:req.body.user_name})
        if(!username) {
            res.send('available')
        } else {
            res.send('none')
        }

    }
```

Will this make the web app slow? Are there any other drawbacks?

Comment: I've modified your question so it's more about facts and less about opinions. If you want more of a review of the code, which works as is, you might want to check the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question is on topic for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

The current approach is not the best when you will talk from the perspective of performance or when you are thinking to scale then the number of API hits would increase exponentially, (it works well for smaller-scale projects).

PS: Though from a UX perspective this is great.

**Better approach 1**

To give a button to check for the availability of the username once done typing.

PS: Not the best UX.

**Better approach 2**

To achieve the best of both worlds, you can wait for the user to types until some minimum number of characters (maybe 4 or 5), and then start calling the API on every char entered, as the username won't be less than 4-5 chars and checking at that length won't be a good idea. Beyond that, it makes sense and gives a great UX as well.

At last, there could be many other ways to go about it, this is according to my perspective. Feel free to comment and add more points to it.

Comment: Great. What about using onfocusout=checkUsername(). I think this will reduce a lot of ajax request!

Comment: Yes, you can use `onBlur` event listener but again user needs to switch back and forth from the username input box to the other one, in order to check the validity of the username. I think that won't be a great UX and would increase the number of clicks for the user.